# JPA error "Cannot merge an entity that has been removed" trying to delete and reinsert a row with SpringData

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I've an Entity (with a primary key that is not generated by a sequence) like this in a Spring Data JPA/Eclipselink environment :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MY_ENTITY")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id 
    @Column(insertable=true, updatable=true, nullable=false)
    private String propertyid;

    \\other columns
}
```

and I'm trying to delete a row from the table and reinsert it (with the same primary key).

My approach is to call deleteAll() to clean the table and then save() the new Entity :

```
    @Transactional
    public void deleteAndSave(MyEntity entity) {
        propertyInfoRepository.deleteAll();
        propertyInfoRepository.flush(); // <- having it or not, nothing changes
        propertyInfoRepository.save(entity);
    }
```

but this gives me this error :

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot merge an entity that has been removed: com.xxx.MyEntity@1f28c51
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.registerObjectForMergeCloneIntoWorkingCopy(MergeManager.java:912)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfCloneIntoWorkingCopy(MergeManager.java:494)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChanges(MergeManager.java:271)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.mergeCloneWithReferences(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3495)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.mergeCloneWithReferences(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:378)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.mergeCloneWithReferences(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3455)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.mergeInternal(EntityManagerImpl.java:486)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.merge(EntityManagerImpl.java:463)
....
```

What am I doing wrong?
I do not understand why it is trying to merge the entity instead of simply reinsert it after its deletion.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly to answer your question:

The problem is that the entity that you try to save has already a persistent identity, i.e an ID, which is why your repository will try to merge, and not to persist the entity.

If you see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559407/spring-data-jpa-save-new-entity-referencing-existing-one) it seems that it is triggered (at least) on the level of the Spring Repository, so you might consider overriding the `save` method of the repository and test whether the problem is still there.

Answer (score -1):

JPA EntityManager keeps track of the state of each managed entity. In your case, you delete the entity and then try to merge it, which raises the exception. I can't tell if your approach is correct (seems weird to delete and then merge) since you don't provide the whole picture but you can try the following:

Assuming `em` is your EntityManager and `entity` your entity:

```
em.remove(entity); //This will perform the delete
MyEntity detachedEntity = em.detach(entity); //Gets a detached copy of the entity, EM will not operated on this unless told to do so (see below)
detachedEntity.setId(null) // Avoid duplicate key violations; Optional since you are deleting the original entity
em.persist(detachedEntity); // This will perform the required insert
```

Comment: I do not try to delete and then merge the entity. Entity is always a new instance (perhaps with the same primary key) and at the moment I call deleteAndSave method, it is not already managed.